# Hearthstone - Finding the fastest lethal for each hero

Tags: hearthstone

I am compiling a list of the fastest ways to kill the opposing hero in Hearthstone. This assumes that the other player does not change their health by armoring up, tapping, or any other means. Also, the opposing player does **not play** any cards, so wins with Millhouse Manastorm are not possible. Assume the player has the Coin.

Here are three 3-turn solutions I have.

## Shaman

```
Turn   Card(s) played     Damage dealer(s)   Opposing hero health
1      Coin
       Dust Devil
       Dust Devil                            30
2                         Dust Devil (6)     24
                          Dust Devil (6)     18
3      Rockbiter Weapon
       Rockbiter Weapon
                          Dust Devil (6)     12
                          Dust Devil (18)    -6
```

## Mage

```
Turn   Card(s) played          Damage dealer(s)            Opposing hero health
1      Mana Wyrm                                           30
2      Sorcerer's Apprentice
       Coin
       Frost Bolt              Frost Bolt (3)              27
       Ice Lance               Ice Lance (4)               23
       Arcane Missiles         Arcane Missiles (3)         20
                               Mana Wyrm (5)               15
3      Fireball                Fireball (6)                9
                               Sorcerer's Apprentice (3)   6
                               Mana Wyrm (6)               0
```

## Rogue

```
Turn   Card(s) played     Damage dealer(s)        Opposing hero health
1      Young Dragonhawk
       Coin
       Cold Blood                                 30
2      Young Dragonhawk
       Cold Blood
                          Young Dragonhawk (10)   20
3                         Young Dragonhawk (10)   10
                          Young Dragonhawk (10)   0
```

And a 2-turn solution.

## Druid

```
Turn   Card(s) played     Damage dealer(s)   Opposing hero health
1      Target Dummy
       Target Dummy
       Innervate
       Innervate
       Mimiron's Head                        30
2      Crazed Alchemist   V-O7-TR-ON (32)    -2
```

Can any of the above be optimized further? Also, what are solutions for other classes? (I suspect Murlocs may be involved in at least one - I have seen a video of a 4-turn Murloc victory.)

Comment: Yes assuming you go against a druid who plays millhouse manastorn on turn 1 with innervate its a turn 1 lethal for most spell based deck assuming enough draw. take mage for example 2 fireballs + 2 pyroblasts+32 damage.

Comment: @hoodlamic1 `Also, the opposing player does not play any cards, so wins with Millhouse Manastorm are not possible.`

Comment: @Rob - No, that's incorrect.  You get four cards for going second, then the coin, then you draw an additional card on the first turn.  You draw the first turn even if you're the player going first.  This is different than other card games, and I suspect it's because the mulligan system is card-based rather than hand-based.